# Boost ability to save an unordered_map to disk

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, c++11

I have an unordered_map below that I would like to save to disk. The problem is my unordered_map contain pointer to my custom class. Would you please show me an example how to accomplish this?

```
boost::unordered_map<char*,boost::variant<macro*,module*>,myhash,cmp_str> *_REF;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make persistent"?

Comment: Hi Nicol, I would like to save the unordered map to disk.

Comment: If it contains pointers, what will those pointers point to when it gets brought back in? You need to serialise the whole data structure at once (not just part of it).

Comment: Thanks Mankarse, when retrieve back the data structure, will the pointer still point to the correct object?

Comment: @BinhVanPham: Yes, but only if it is in the same run of the program, and only if those objects still exist.

Comment: Thank Mankarse, then I have to use boost::unordered_map<char*,boost::variant<macro,module>,myhash,cmp_str> *_REF;  to be able to save and retrieve safely?  Please note the boost::variant<macro,module> difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of serialization mechanism for saving the contents of the map to the disk.
I would recommend looking at Boost Serialization library for this purpose:

http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, the problem is my hash using variant which take in the pointer instead of object. So I was wondering if serialization in this case will be able to write the hash to the disk and retrieve the hash intact?  Thanks Dimitri

Comment: Hope this is still relevant...You need to define a serialize method specific to your map element type. For details, check out this link: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html